# Reorganizing an excel workbook based on values in one column into many columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Excel table that I would like to reorganize:

[image]

I'd like to reorganize the table in which all the "Types" in Column B, have their own column. All the "Sites" in Column A, only have unique values and all the "Area" values in Column C fill their position in relation to the Site and Type. See the desired output example below:

[image]

These are just examples of a much larger dataset, but the task is the same. I am familiar with VBA and was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem, what functions or procedures could help reorganize my table?

Comment: looks like a job for a pivot table, plenty to read up online about it, just search "pivot table excel", one guide here: [Pivot Tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

Comment: This question is a bit broad for SO (not a specific coding question/issue).  However, @Raugmor is absolutely right on track with suggesting a Pivot Table.

Comment: The Pivot Table did exactly what I needed. Quick and Simple solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This assumes that the input is on *Sheet1* and the output will be placed on *Sheet2*

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant
    Dim r As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = sh1.Range("A2:A" & N)
    Set r2 = sh1.Range("B2:B" & N)
    Set r3 = sh2.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)
    Set r4 = sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, 2), sh2.Cells(1, Columns.Count))
    Call ExtractUniques(r1, r3)
    Call ExtractUniques(r2, r4)

    For i = 2 To N
        v1 = sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        v2 = sh1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        v3 = sh1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        j = 2
        k = 2

        For Each r In r3
            If v1 = r.Value Then
                Exit For
            Else
            j = j + 1
            End If
        Next r
        For Each r In r4
            If v2 = r.Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
            k = k + 1
        Next r
        sh2.Cells(j, k).Value = v3
    Next i
End Sub

Sub ExtractUniques(rIn As Range, rOut As Range)
    Dim C As Collection, r As Range
    Set C = New Collection
    Dim cC As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rIn
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            C.Add r.Value, CStr(r.Value)
        End If
    Next r
    cC = C.Count
    i = 1
    For Each r In rOut
        r.Value = C.Item(i)
        i = i + 1
        If i > cC Then Exit Sub
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why the O.P. approved this answer when he said in his comments that a Pivot Table solved his problem...

Comment: @Chrismas007 Both approaches are valid.......because this is **Stackoverflow** I posted a *programmatic solution.*